# Programmatically query Event Hub Consumer Group (and create if required)

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-sdk-.net

Does anyone know how to query and create consumer groups in Azure Event Hubs using the .NET SDK.  I've googled loads and can only find a way through the REST API (which I can do, but it would nicer if I can do it through the SDK).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to query and create consumer groups in Azure Event Hubs using the .NET SDK.

You could try to install [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/), and as Sreeram said, we could use the `NamespaceManager class` to create consumer group.

```
var manager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("{your connection string}");
manager.CreateConsumerGroupIfNotExists("{eventHubPath}", "{consumergroup Name}");
```

After you executed the code, you will find the consumer group is created.

[image]

To get the consumer group, you could try to call [EventHubClient.GetConsumerGroup method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.getconsumergroup?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubClient_GetConsumerGroup_System_String_).

```
var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("{your connection string}");
var client = factory.CreateEventHubClient("{eventHubPath}"); 
EventHubConsumerGroup group = client.GetConsumerGroup("{consumergroup Name}");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`NamespaceManager.CreateConsumerGroupIfNotExistsAsync`(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.createconsumergroupifnotexistsasync?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0)

```
ConsumerGroupDescription realtimeCG = nsMgr.CreateConsumerGroupIfNotExists("PartitionedStream_AKA_EventHub_Name");
```